# Break point on every page in Chrome Canary

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know why but everytime there is an error on the JavaScript of a page Chrome Canary just stops rendering the page and it just loads forever. In the screenshot below I just type "x" in the console, it is undefined but why did it have to go and break the whole thing. It could just output the error on the console itself. Maybe I was able to change some setting in chrome but I don't what specific setting it is. Is there any way to maybe reset Chrome settings?Because the way the browser is acting now is that its as if I've set a breakpoint on every page that I visit on the browser. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem in your screenshot--if you look at the row of buttons on the very bottom, you'll see the fourth one, the stop sign with the little pause button, is blue. If you hover over it, it says "Pause on all exceptions". Click it until it turns black, and the tooltip says "Don't pause on exceptions".

Comment: thanks! I never thought it was the pause button that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it configured somewhere to break on errors.  I would suggest clearing all breakpoints unless you specifically need one enabled.  Keep in mind that if you have a break point configured... all execution and processing (and downloading) of pages stops... until you tell it to resume processing.